# How do I use a certain version (or higher) of a perl module in my perl script?

Tags: perl, version, perl-module

I'm using `Term::ANSIColor` in my Perl script to do colorization of terminal output, and I am using the `colorstrip` function, which was only added in `Term::ANSIColor` version 2.01, according to the changelog. So, is there a way to make my script automatically `die` with an appropriate error message if it doesn't find at least that version of `Term::ANSIcolor`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just:

```
use Term::ANSIColor 2.01;
```

See [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

> use Module VERSION LIST
>
> If the VERSION argument is present between Module and LIST, then the use will call the VERSION method in class Module with the given version as an argument. The default VERSION method, inherited from the UNIVERSAL class, croaks if the given version is larger than the value of the variable $Module::VERSION .

Answer (score 8):

Most modules define the package variable `$VERSION`.

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
die "Sorry, this program needs Term::ANSIColor >= v2.01!\n"
    unless $Term::ANSIColor::VERSION >= 2.01;
```

This is also a good way to specify a *maximum* version of a module.

```
use Module::Foo;
die "You need an *older* version of Module::Foo that ",
    "still has the &barbaz method defined"
    if $Module::Foo::VERSION >= 0.47;
```

Comment: It's a fine way to do it. When you supply a version in the import list, you rely on the import method actually handling this. Not only that, the import technique only requires that version or later. If you want a particular version or range of versions, you end up with this more general technique.

Comment: Actually there's no help needed from the `import` method -- when you use `use` or `require` with a version number, a call is generated to the `VERSION` method. But every package that doesn't specifically override it gets a suitable `VERSION` method from `UNIVERSAL`.

Comment: @brian probably should have tagged you on the previous message, so now I am :)

Comment: hobbs is right about the VERSION thing, but I was focussing on the "version or later" bit and thinko-d the method name. I can't edit it now.

Comment: @briandfoy supplying a version on the use line is different from supplying it in the import list; the former is handled by perl separate from the call to import (if any).  Though it is helpful that Exporter does support a version in the import list so that -MFoo=1.23 works (supposing Foo uses Exporter)

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the version you want to use:

```
use Some::Module 2.13;
```

If the version is not at least 2.13, the operation will fail.

You can experiment with the version that is available on the command line:

```
perl -MSome::Module=9999 -e 'exit 0'
```

This will usually die with the wrong version number shown in the error message (unless the module you're trying to use happens to have a 5 digit or longer version number, or unless the module is like `strict` and doesn't like being loaded via the command line with a version number or like `URI` (see the comments for details)).

```
$ perl -MFile::Find=999 -e 'exit 0'
File::Find version 999 required--this is only version 1.07 at
/usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/Exporter/Heavy.pm line 121.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
$ perl -e 'use File::Find 999; exit 0'
File::Find version 999 required--this is only version 1.07 at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
$
```

Run on a machine I don't normally use, hence the antiquated version of Perl.

Comment: The two are subtly different; the command line -M switch never specifies a VERSION to use; instead it supplies it as a parameter to the module's import routine, and modules that use Exporter then do a version check.  But not all modules use Exporter.

Comment: This doesn't work reliably with all modules, so it's not a general technique, as ysth says.

Comment: @ysth and @brian: OK - I take your word for it; I've not tried it on every module in CPAN, but the only time I've run into a problem with version numbers is with sub-modules of a main module that do not reliably set their own version.  Can you give an instance or two of modules where it doesn't work?

Comment: @ysth: can you update `strict` separately from the version of Perl?  What version variations are there on `strict`?  You're right, it (`use strict;`) doesn't like having arguments like the version number.
I just tried to update 'strict' with CPANPLUS and got told: `Installing strict (1.04)
[ERROR] The core Perl 5.013004 module 'strict' (1.04) can only be installed by Perl itself. Aborting install.`  So, version testing `strict` is not useful; you need to version test Perl.  Can you give any alternative examples?

Comment: You're missing the point...`use strict 1.04;` is perfectly legitimate, but -Mstrict=1.04 does something very different (and so doesn't work).

Comment: @ysth: OK; I'm missing your point; you're missing my point.  We'd probably best just agree to differ.  Those who come after can work out what's relevant, if anything, from this discussion.

Comment: Another example: URI.  A pure OO module, URI has no exports and doesn't use Exporter, so -MURI=9999 does no version checking at all, while `use URI 9999` does.

Comment: @ysth: thank you - a much better example.  I've updated the answer to reflect the commentary.